# Azure App Configuration with WPF using managed identity

Tags: wpf, azure, azure-app-configuration

I'm trying to get values from azure app configuration in my WPF application using managed identity but I can't figure out how to connect those things.

In WPF app I'm using **IPublicClientApplication** from *Microsoft.Identity.Client* to authenticate user and get the user token as follows

```
            var accounts = await IdentityClient.GetAccountsAsync();
            AuthenticationResult? result1 = null;

            try
            {
                result1 = await IdentityClient
                    .AcquireTokenSilent(Constants.Scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                    .ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
            {
                result1 = await IdentityClient
                    .AcquireTokenInteractive(Constants.Scopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Error: Authentication failed: {ex.Message}");
            }
```

To create connection with app configuration I was trying to use **ConfigurationClient** from  *Azure.Data.AppConfiguration*, but I don't know how to use this to create app configuration client because second parameter should be TokenCredential object.

```
var client = new ConfigurationClient(new Uri("https://xxx.azconfig.io"), ???);
```

Is there another library that I should use in WPF to connect azure app configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom implementation of TokenCredential. Please see this document for more details: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/samples/DefiningCustomCredentialTypes.md

Comment: so there is no easy or out-of-the-box solution? this is weird for me, and I have a feeling that I'm not doing the right way here